# Selecting 2 values from different tables not related and perform operations with results BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need some help with SQL in Google Big Query.

I have two tables, A and B, I need to select a value from A and another value from B that are not related and, perform a mathematical operation.

```
TABLE A

NAME        |      TIMESTAMP
------------------------------
xyz         |      2013-01-02 
abcd        |      2013-01-02
efgh        |      2012-03-01
```

```
TABLE B

CAMPAING    |         DATE      | COST
-------------------------------------------
A          |      2013-01-02    |  10   
B          |      2013-01-02    |  30
C          |      2012-03-01    |  15
```

What I manage to do:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT NAME)
FROM `TABLE A`
WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP) = '2013-01-02'

UNION DISTINCIT

SELECT (SUM(COST))
FROM `TABLE B`
WHERE date = '2013-01-02'
```

Output:

```
ROW |    f0_
----------------
1   |     2
2   |     40
```

What I need to do is to divide those two values... 40/2

Desired output:

```
ROW |    f0_
----------------
1   |     20
```

Can anyone help me to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries:

```
SELECT a.cnt, b.cost, b.cost / a.cnt
FROM (SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) as cnt
      FROM `TABLE A`
      WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP) = '2013-01-02'
     ) a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(COST) as cost
      FROM `TABLE B`
      WHERE date = '2013-01-02'
     ) b;
```